# Show 2 columns in 2 different rows - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to separate two columns into two rows in sql

I have this:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
Car       2         5
Boat      4
Truck               6
```

And I want this:

```
Column1   Column2
Car       2
Car       5
Boat      4
Truck     6
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: You can use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This operation is unpivoting.  I would recommend `apply`:

```
select t.column1, v.col
from t cross apply
     (values (col1), (col2)) v(col)
where v.col is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
select Column1,   Column2
from tbl where Column2 is not null and Column2 <> ''
union
select Column1,   Column3
from tbl where Column3 is not null and Column3 <> ''
```